# Email Attachments missing on Azure, works locally

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid, mailmessage

I have implemented something similar to the following question and I can get it working locally on my server, but when I deploy to Azure it doesn't work. I don't get any errors: just an email without the attachment.

[Sending attachments using Azure blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097590/sendgrid-how-to-attach-a-file-from-azure-blob-storage?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Are there restrictions on what types of files can be sent with SendGrid (file is only 56k)? 
Does the Azure App service have to be at a particular level or can it be done on Basic?
The blob URL definitley exists and I am setting the stream to zero as suggested in that previous question.

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("receiver address", "someone");
            mm.From = new MailAddress("myAddress", "My Name");
            mm.Subject = content.Subject;
            mm.Body = content.Body;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            var attachmentAsStream = _storageAccessService.GetAssetAsStreamForEmail("myContainer", "fileThatExists.pdf");

            var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentAsStream, "File.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);


public MemoryStream GetAssetAsStreamForEmail(string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = StorageAccountReference().CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            try
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Failed to download Email Atatchment: "+ ex.Message));

            }
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return memoryStream;
        }

using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Port = 587;
                    client.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Timeout = 10000;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hidden", "hidden");

                    await client.SendMailAsync(message);
                }
```

---

*Update*

Update after Yasir's suggestion below. Downloading the blob from Azure as a Stream only seems to work locally. But if I change to download as a ByteArray then it works everywhere, nonetheless...

```
public MemoryStream GetAssetAsStreamForEmail(string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = StorageAccountReference().CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            try
            {
                blob.FetchAttributes();
                var fileStream = new byte[blob.Properties.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < blob.Properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    fileStream[i] = 0x20;
                }

                blob.DownloadToByteArray(fileStream, 0) ;
                MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream(fileStream);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Failed to download Email Atatchment: " + ex.Message));

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me for sending emails using Sendgrid from Azure functions. I attach a CSV file from Blob Storage. It should work for you as well. All you will have to do is ensure that you read the pdf file as a byte[].

```
    public interface IEmailAttachment
    {
        string Name { get; }
        byte[] FileData { get; }
    }

    public static void Send(MailMessage mailMessage, IEnumerable<IEmailAttachment> attachments)
    {
    try
    {
        // Get the configuration data
        string server = ConfigReader.EmailServer;
        int port = ConfigReader.EmailPort;
        string username = ConfigReader.SendGridUserName;
        string password = ConfigReader.SendGridPassword;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        // Create the SMTP Client
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(server, port);

        // Prepare the MailMessage
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigReader.FromEmail);

        var toEmails = ConfigReader.ToEmail.Split(',');

        foreach (var toEmail in toEmails)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(toEmail);
        }

        var ccEmails = ConfigReader.EmailCc.Split(',');

        foreach (var ccEmail in ccEmails)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(ccEmail);
        }


        // Add attachments
        List<MemoryStream> files = new List<MemoryStream>();

        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (IEmailAttachment file in attachments)
            {
                MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream(file.FileData);
                files.Add(bufferStream);

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(bufferStream, file.Name);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        // Send the email
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        foreach (MemoryStream stream in files)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good shout on the byte array. Downloading from Azure as a ByteArray appears to work, over a Stream