# Attaching Azure Blob from stream to SendGrid email

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, sendgrid

I'm attempting to send an Azure Blob as an attachment via SendGrid. My first step is to download the blob as such:

```
download_client=BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=az_str, 
        container_name=container_name, 
        blob_name=blob_name) 

download_stream = download_client.download_blob()
```

I have found that SendGrid has the functionality to add files from memory with NodeJS, however I did not find anything like that with Python. [SendGrid GitHub](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/b57b32caa47608a15d23940a0dedc82a91e7b6aa#addfile)

Does anyone know how to do this with Python?

I also found this article on Stack that is more-or-less the same question but not in python and not answered directly. 
[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097590/sendgrid-how-to-attach-a-file-from-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question?

Comment: Got me. Edited it for ya.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

There is an attachment module under the `sendgrid.helpers.mail`, you could refer to here: [Attachment](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/use_cases/attachment.md). Below is my test code, maybe you could have a try.

```
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *
import base64
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from io import BytesIO

message = Mail(
    from_email='from_email@example.com',
    to_emails='to@example.com',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')

connect_str ='storage connection string'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blobclient=blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='test',blob='nodejschinesedoc.pdf')
streamdownloader =blobclient.download_blob()
stream = BytesIO()
streamdownloader.download_to_stream(stream)


encoded = base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue()).decode()
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment.file_name = FileName('test_filename.pdf')
attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
message.attachment = attachment
try:
    sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient('sendgrid API key')
    response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
```